# Using Python to scrape point information from embedded google map

Tags: python, html, google-maps, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am trying to use the requests library + beautiful soup to pull information on the antenna points from the map shown on this website.

http://www.sites.bipt.be/

My original plan was to iterate through site numbers, pull out the lat/long information that appears on the left hand panel when a point is clicked, and display that data in Arc. So far I have accessed the  element where that information is located when the point is clicked ( id = selectedsite ... ). But the element turns up empty in python seemingly because nothing is clicked?

This is my first time web scraping and I have limited HTML knowlege, if there is another approach that would be better or any pointers you could offer that would be greatly appreciated :)

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    #api_key = 'MY_API_KEY'

    #Prettify HTML
    source = requests.get("http://www.sites.bipt.be/").text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
    print(soup.prettify())


    # Class where information on the selected site is located - turns up empty
    div = soup.find(id='selectedsite')
    print(div.prettify())
```

Comment: You have to
 use `soup.find('div', {'id': 'selectedsite'})`

Comment: I've removed your API key from your question. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey

Answer (score 0):

This webpage loads data with `JavaScript`. You cannot use `BeautifulSoup` to click on an element in a webpage. You have to use `selenium`.